# Query multiple table relationships using Laravel Eloquent Models

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to query multiple tables using **Laravel Eloquent Models** with *one to one*, *one to many* and *many to many* relationships.

I have a `forms` table, a `brands` table a `users` table and a `brand_groups` **pivot** table.

Each form has one brand and one user:

```
forms
  ID
  user_id
  brand_id
```

Brands do not have any foreign keys:

```
brands
  ID
```

Users do not have any foreign keys:

```
users
  ID
```

And there is a pivot table to create a *many to many* relationship for creating brand groups that have many users like brand members:

```
brand_groups
  brand_id
  user_id
```

I'm trying to get all the forms that belong to a user either by a direct ownership (`forms.user_id`) or by brand membership, all the forms from all the brands that the user is a member through `brand_groups` many to many pivot table.

For example, we have 2 brands, 2 users and 1 user is a member of 1 brand:

```
brand(ID: 1)
brand(ID: 2)

user(ID: 1)
user(ID: 2)

brand_group(brand_id: 1, user_id: 1)

form(ID: 1, user_id: 1,    brand_id: null)
form(ID: 2, user_id: null, brand_id: 1)
form(ID: 3, user_id: 2,    brand_id: 1)
form(ID: 4, user_id: 1,    brand_id: 2)
```

Using **Laravel Eloquent Models** (*not direct DB facade calls*), I'd like to retrieve all the forms that belong to a user. For the `user(ID:1)` there are 3 forms:

`form(ID:1)` direct user ownership
`form(ID:2)` user is a member of `brand(ID:1)` group which is the brand of `form(ID:2)`
`form(ID:3)` user is a member of `brand(ID:1)` group which is the brand of `form(ID:3)`

I gave it a shot using [Eloquent: Relationships - Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

> #### [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)
>
> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient way to access distant relations via an intermediate relation.

I have tried it like this:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function forms()
    {
        return Forms::hasManyThrough(
            Form::class,
            BrandGroups::class,
            'brand_id',
            'brand_id',
            'id',
            'form_id',
        )->where('id', $this->id);
    }
}
```

But I get errors like:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App\Models\Form::brand_groups()'
```

**EDIT**

After some digging, I have managed to come up with the working MySQL code that will return all the forms for a user:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `forms`
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT `brand_id`, `user_id`
  FROM `brand_groups`
  WHERE `forms`.`brand_id` = `brand_groups`.`brand_id`
    AND `brand_groups`.`user_id` = 1
) OR `forms`.`user_id` = 1
```

Now I just need to convert that query to an eloquent model relation.

### Eloquent Models

#### `User.php`

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'brand_groups')
            ->using(BrandGroups::class)
            ->as('member');
    }

    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Form::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

#### `Brand.php`

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';

    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Form::class);
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(User::class, 'brand_groups')
            ->using(BrandGroups::class)
            ->as('member');
    }
}
```

#### `Form.php`

```php
class Form extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'forms';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I manage to find a query to get all forms related to a user like this:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    ...

    public function allForms()
    {
        return Form::where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereExists(function ($q) {
                $q->from('brand_groups')
                    ->where('forms.brand_id', DB::raw('brand_groups.brand_id'))
                    ->where('brand_groups.user_id', $this->id);
            })->orWhere('owner_id', $this->id);
        });
    }
}
```

How this can be converted to a direct `User` model eloquent relationship?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the User model relationships?

**Edit**
Firstly: the pivot table name should be the singular -snake_case- name of both tables and should be in alphabetical order (brand_user)

Next, try the following:

```
return User::where(‘id’, $this->id)->with([‘forms’,‘brands.forms’)->get();
```

This should return the Forms with direct ownership plus the user Brands and their associated Forms

Comment: **ERROR** `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [brand_groups] on model [App\Models\Form].'` There is no direct relationship of the `forms` table and the `brand_groups` table; `brand_groups` table is the pivot table that connects `users` with `brands`.

Comment: Can you please post your models?

Comment: I have updated my question with the eloquent models and their relationships.

Comment: I edited my answer, try and keep it updated.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look onto this problem. Without any modification, your edited eloquent query works, but it doesn't group the forms to a single collection, so I get all the forms that the user is an owner with `<query>->forms` and then I get a collection of all the brands that the user belongs to using the `<query>->brands<each>->forms` which is a great step (*upvoted for that*), but I'd like to have a query that I can get all the forms in **one collection**. I know it's posible; do you know how I would achieve the query to get all the forms in a single collection?

Comment: Try using the pluck() helper method. I didn’t test this. return User::where(‘id’, $this->id)->with([‘forms’,‘brands’)->get()->pluck([‘forms’,’brands.forms’]);

Comment: I'd like to get all the forms collection using a single query without any manual collection traversing. I managed to do this and you can check my question update to see how. Do you know how I can convert `User::find(1)->allForms` to a direct relationship to the `User` model?

Comment: I’m sorry Christos, I can’t seem to get your last point

Comment: With your query I get a tree. With the query I posted at the end of my question I get a flat array directly without the need to traverse the result and convert it to array. That query I posted does the job but it's not a direct relationship to the `User` model and I'm not sure if it can be since the relationship derives from 2 different tables.